# How do I remove this door handle?

Tags: doors, doorknob

I'm attempting to remove this door handle with no success. I cannot figure out how to remove the plate on the front. It seems impossible to just pry it off.

How can I remove this door handle? Also, is anyone able to identify this door knob such that I can find its manual?

[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT: I was able to remove the rose by turning it with channel locks. I was also able to determine that this is a Karcher door level/knob. However, I cannot remove the spindle and thus cannot remove the latch. How can I remove this spindle?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The latch does not remove until the handle and mechanism removes.  Are you working on the correct side of the door? One side is made tamper resistant and has no accessible fasteners.

Comment: @Harper Both sides of the door seem very similar, hard to tell which side might be more accessible. Is there any photo I could take to provide better context?

Comment: It looks very similar to this handle from B&Q https://www.diy.com/departments/ayen-satin-nickel-effect-internal-straight-latch-rose-handle-pair/1832149_BQ.prd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the hole in the bottom of the handle there is a screw, an allen or slotted, that has to be loosened to remove the handle. Then the other handle should pull out with the stem. The slide bolt then can be pulled out since you've already removed the screws.

Comment: I removed a screw in the handles on both sides, but they don't seem to budge. Is there supposed to be something deeper?

Comment: Try grabbing both handles and twisting them back and forth while trying to pull them apart.

Comment: also, see if you can turn the round silver covers

Comment: Twisting and pulling doesn't seem to do anything. If I turn it enough the whole mechanism turns, but obviously I don't want to do that as it may damage the door.

Comment: The round silver covers don't really turn either. They seem to be almost part of the whole thing.

Comment: I second try to turn the covers. rotating a few degrees may bring them to a place where they pop off. Did you try grabbing them with some large channel locks over a cloth or some shelf liner rubber / plastic?

Comment: @BrianK I don't have any channel locks large enough, any other tool that might get the job done?

Comment: Along these lines, I had a lockset on my back door that had no screws at all. A pin held the inside handle on, and had to be driven out using a nail. Removing that handle let me remove the rest. I had to replace the lockset because the spring that pushed the latchbolt out was failing (strong winds would occasionally push the locked door open).

Comment: I was able to remove part of the knob, but I cannot remove the spindle. I've updated my question with more details.

Comment: Do those two latches on the top and bottom of the slide unlock the spindle??

Comment: The latches on the top and bottom seem to just open/close when the spindle turns. I've tried pulling them back and it doesn't seem to be freeing the spindle, unless I'm doing something wrong

Comment: You're referring to the top of the internal tubulur part, correct?

Comment: Yes,  that's the part I'm referring  to,  the latches on the top and bottom.